# Use a file as a buffer for a producer consumer system of two programs

Tags: c++, file, ipc

I have two programs one of which writes some entries into a file and the other one reads all the entries from the file an processes them.

Currently, the files are executed sequentially. That means, the first programs produces the file completely and exits before the second program is run. Now I want, without much modifications that the second program can be run simultaneously in a producer-consumer fashion. I know I should use interprocess communication, but at this point I want to make minimal changes the programs to get the running.

Specifically, I want that the second program processes the entries from the second file in real time as they are generated by the first file.

I am using gcc on ubuntu 11.04

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: linux (Ubuntu 11.04) gcc

Comment: A big problem with using files as a "buffer" between threads is the file pointer. By nature, the reader will always have to be behind the "writer" (or waiting on it) but if the OS only allows one file pointer per file you end up with a rather awkward situation. Pipes are definitely the way to go--Rob has an awesome answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a Unix-like operating system, may I suggest [pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)? Modify your first program to write to  standard output (instead of opening a file and passing references that `ofstream` around, pass `std::cout`). Modify your 2nd program to read from standard input (ditto, but replace your `ifstream` references with `std::cin`).

Then, instead of

```
prog1 -o some-tmp-file.txt
prog2 -i some-tmp-file.txt
```

do this:

```
prog1 | prog2
```

---

**EDIT**: If your existing programs are based on `<cstdio>` instead of `<iostream>`, the same principle applies. Use `stdout` instead of your existing `FILE*` in the first program. Uses `stdin` instead of your `FILE*` in the second program.

---

**EDIT #2**: If you want to make absolutely no change to the second program, and perhaps only minimal changes to the first program, try using [named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).

```
mkfifo /tmp/some-tmp-file.txt
prog2 -i /tmp/some-temp-file.txt &
prog1 -o /tmp/some-temp-file.txt
```

Comment: +1 I would say that's the safest and easiest solution for the question.

Comment: this is a superb solution except that the program 1 is using standard output for some other purpose :(

Comment: @AnkurVj: Then try "Edit #2".

Comment: +1 Definitely a far better way to handle process communication than writing to files.